# Большие буквы в названии памятника

Tags: прописная-строчная

Здравствуйте!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать название памятника погибшим кораблям? В смысле, какие слова будут писаться с прописной буквы?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это официальное название памятника, его собственное наименование, то правильно *памятник Погибшим кораблям*.

В составных названиях памятников с прописной буквы пишется первое слово и имена собственные: памятник Пушкину, памятник «Родина-мать».

Если это неофициальное, нарицательное наименование - *памятник погибшим кораблям*.

Answer (score 0):

Памятник погибшим кораблям  расположен в Севастополе, напротив Приморского бульвара, в десяти метрах от берега и представляет собой триумфальную семиметровую колонну с обращенным в сторону моря двуглавым орлом на ее капители. Орел держит в своих клювах венок с якорем.

Интересно то, что многие (даже экскурсоводы) путают название этого памятника и  называют его памятником погибшим кораблям или памятником затонувшим кораблям, что является ошибкой. Решение затопить в 1854 и 1855 годах ряд кораблей  сделало невозможным для вражеских судов вход в Севастопольскую бухту в ходе Первой обороны Севастополя.

http://clubs.ya.ru/4611686018427398066/replies.xml?item_no=241357

Написание самого знаменитого памятника Севастополя также имеет много вариантов, например:

Памятник затопленным кораблям, "Памятник Затопленным Кораблям",  памятник затопленным кораблям,  памятник Затопленным кораблям.

Какой из них является верным? Можно предположить следующие варианты:

(1) Нарицательное наименование: памятник затопленным  кораблям.

(2) Официальное название: монумент «В память кораблей, затопленных в 1854—1855 году для заграждения входа в рейд».

(3) Неофициальные названия имени собственного: Памятник затопленным кораблям или (редко)памятник Затопленным кораблям. Второй вариант мне кажется неудачным: всё-таки этот монумент не кораблям, а в память о кораблях.

Вариант с кавычками уместен только в официальном  названии.